# Rely on session var not existing to see if cookies are disabled

Tags: php, cookies

Logic, the manual and Google say I'm right, but I'm no pro and I like to be 100% sure it is working for all browsers, in any circumstance.

I'd like to check if a user has cookies disabled in his browser. I cannot rely on `isset($_COOKIE['test']`, because when it's a new user or the user deleted all cookies, there will be no cookie and cookies still can be enabled.
I came up with a very simple solution, but my question is: can I be sure this to works?

If page 1 is: **domain/index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']='Hello';
session_write_close();
header('Location: login');
?>
```

And page 2 is: **domain/login/index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo 'Turn on your cookies!';
    }
?>
```

Will this always work?
**[edit]**
To answer my own question: no, this will not work.

I've posted a working solution below.
Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Seems like you are confused with `sessions` and `cookies`

Comment: Probably not - A 'Please turn on your cookies.' is more effective

Comment: session id can be stored in server also...

Comment: set session.use_cookies=on and session.use_only_cookies=on

Comment: Am I right the session_id is stored in a cookie? But wil a redirect generate a new session_id or use the same?

Comment: up to end of the life it will use unique session id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for pointing me in the right direction.

My solution works, so I'll share it with you:

**index.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies',1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',1);


$name='test';
if(empty($_COOKIE[$name]){
    session_start();
    //it seems nessecary to write something in the session
    $_SESSION['test']=test;
    session_write_close();
    }

//redirect to a login page
header('Location: http://example.com/login/');
}
?>
```

And **login/index.php**

```
<?php
$name='test';
if(empty($_COOKIE[$name])){
  echo 'Turn on your cookies';
die;
}
?>
```

See [the manual on sessions and cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies)